# Probability of a Poisson Point Process

Tags: probability-theory, poisson-process

If I have a poisson point process $N(t)$ with $\lambda=1$, and I am interested in $P(N(t) \geq 2t)$, how would I go about solving this? Would it just be a product of poisson CDF calculations?

Comment: Do you mean, for fixed $t$, the probability that $N(t)\ge2$ or, the probability that $N(t)\ge2t$ for all $t$, that is, of the event  $\bigcap_{t\ge0}[N(t)\ge 2t]$?

Comment: For fixed $t$ you just sum the probabilities of the Poisson mass function with parameter $\lambda t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a fixed $t>0$, we have
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N(t)\geqslant 2t) &= \mathbb P(N(t)\geqslant \lceil 2t\rceil)\\
&= \sum_{n=\lceil 2t \rceil}^\infty \mathbb P(N(t)=n)\\
&= \sum_{n=\lceil 2t \rceil}^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}.
\end{align}
There isn't really a nice closed form for this expression, but Mathematica gives me this:
$$
1-\frac{\Gamma (\lceil 2 t\rceil ,\lambda t)}{\Gamma (\lceil 2 t\rceil )},
$$
where $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}\ \mathsf dx$ is the Gamma function and $\Gamma(s,x) = \int_x^\infty t^{s-1}e^{-t}\ \mathsf dt$ is the upper incomplete gamma function. The case where $\lambda=1$ does not particularly simplify things.